# Grid gain node stops automatically on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, gridgain

I am using gridgain version 6.1.9 and have setup couple of nodes on amazon ec2. I have configured tcp discovery for discovering the nodes. The nodes startup fine and also join each other.   but after a few minutes ( around 20 minutes ), grid gain node stops with message

```
    **GridGain node stopped OK [uptime=00:21:53:493]**
```

I have set the socket timeout to 30 seconds. Is there any thing else that I might have missed configuring ?

Comment: Are there any other error messages on any of the nodes? The only way a grid node would stop is if it got the CTRL-C signal. Are you sure that your amazon instance is not being shutdown?

Comment: @Tadaka You can try disabling automatic shutdown hook. It can be done by setting `-DGRIDGAIN_NO_SHUTDOWN_HOOK=true` system property. It will ignore the CTRL-C signals if it was the reason for the stop.

Comment: @Dmitriy thanks ... It was a nrpe process that was doing it...